# Open CV Compilation Raspberry Pi 3 Raspbian Jesse

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, opencv3.0

I've been trying to compile the Open CV library on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Jesse. I'm wondering if Open CV versions 2.4.x will work on my Pi 3 and what the differences are between versions 2.x and 3.0. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why settle for 2.4 when 3.0 compiles and builds fine?

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between OpenCV 2.4.x and OpenCV 3.0 (some modules moved and there are more contributions available), but unless you're using the latest, cutting edge algorithms available in OpenCV right now, 2.4 should do.

Additionally compiling OpenCV will take a while. it's faster to compile on Raspberry Pi 3 than older models, but still fairly slow slow.
Unless you setup a cross compilation environment (which can be cumbersome), reiteration can be a bit slow using a compiled language like c++.

I recommend trying OpenCV in Python. It's much faster to prototype scripting on Raspberry Pi. You might not have 100% of the functionalities available in c++,
but the most common features are there.
Here are couple of nice starter articles:

- [Install OpenCV and Python on your Raspberry Pi 2 and B+](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/)
- [Accessing the Raspberry Pi Camera with OpenCV and Python](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/)